# How to deploy GCP Applications across multiple zones in a region

Tags: google-cloud-platform

According to the link below, GCloud recommends deploying applications across multiple zones in a region. Does any one have a guide on how to do this? For example - are instance groups basically clones of a single instance, grouped into one? Can I point one instance to multiple zones in a region?

Thanks for your consideration.

SE

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps

Answer (score 2):

Simplified a [managed instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) is a set of identical instances that can be placed behind a [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/) to serve requests. The instances characteristics are defined in a [template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#instance_templates). GCP can use this template to add or delete VMs ([autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/)) according to the load.

You will setup behind your load balancer [backends services](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service) that are composed by managed instance groups. Those MIG can be setup [in different zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances). You can also use [Regional Managed instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/distributing-instances-with-regional-instance-groups) where the instances of the group will be spread in different zones.